# using PKI module from powershell

Tags: powershell, azure, pki, azure-powershell

I would like to create a self signed certificate using powershell as shown in `https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/cloud-services-certs-create/`.

The command New-SelfSignedCertificate threw an error - 
New-SelfSignedCertificate : The term 'New-SelfSignedCertificate' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function,
script file, or operable program.

So, I installed PackageManagement PowerShell Modules Preview - March 2016

After that when I run Find-Module PKI it gives me an error- PackageManagement\Find-Package : No match was found for the specified search criteria and module name 'PKI'.

I'm using Win7 as OS.

Comment: The `PKI` module ships as part of the Windows operating system - but not until Windows 8 or newer

Comment: What is the output from `$PSVersionTable`

Comment: @Burt_Harris Powershell 3

Comment: I saw PSPKI but unable to convert the code in article to the same